# What is the best way to create a viewController of iPad?

Tags: ios

I'm developing an universal app, but i have some troubles about viewController of iPad. What is the best way for the sizes of images be the correct size of device, Autolayout or create a new storyboard for iPad?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of Xcode uses one storyboard for both iPad and iPhones. Within Interface Builder, you can customize the layout for various screen sizes by clicking the bottom of IB where it says "w Any h Any".

Paul Hegarty of Stanford covers AutoLayout extensively in [CS193p in Lecture 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-61-MCBGnrY), which you may find helpful if you're just getting started with iOS.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. But my question is about of design. For example, in the lecture, Paul Hegarty has two UITextField that cover all display, including the iPad. But the design in the iPad does not cover all display. Those things are more convenient to work with another storyboard or Autolayout?

Comment: On the bottom of IB, you can select various display sizes and set constraints for various configurations (compact, etc)

Answer (score 0):

if we are specifically talking about images , the you could make use of Images.xcassets , where you create a an image with 3 sizes 1x , 2x and 3x and it is rendered automatically in runtime , for example if you have an image with 20x20 pixels , it will be the same size in 1x and 40x40 in 2x and 60x60 in 3x .
additional info : 
IPhone 4 , 4s , 5 , 5s and 5c are rendered at 2x 
IPhone 6+ is rendered at 3x